# How to update drop down values with postback(Client Side) in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one radio button list and one drop down list inside the modal popup extender in my asp.net web application.Two radio buttons are there in the radio button list such as r1,r2. Drop down list having values like A,B,C,D,E,F. I need when I select r1 it will fills the values A,B,C in the Drop down list. When I select r2 it will fills the values E,F in the drop down. But one condition the page will not to be post pack. Can any one know the solution for that problem? I will really helpful for my project.

Thank you...

Comment: You can do that with jQuery help and some javascript. There are a lot of examples that you can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jquery to add/remove items. You can attach to the radio buttons click event like this. This code is untested, but should be fairly approximate.

```
$("#radiobuttonid").click(function() {
  //put your code here for clearingout the select list
  $('#ddlMyCombo >option').remove();
  //now put new items in the dropdown, repeat as many times as necessary
  var myCombo1= $('#ddlMyCombo');
  myCombo1.append($('< option > </option>').val(1).html(option1Text));
});
```